# Creating object in VB6 for use with an object from a dll(tlb) written in c#?

Tags: c#, vb6, vb6-migration

So my knowledge in vb6 is rather limited, but required for this, since it's old code.

I've created a dll, with an object (class of strings) in c#.

What is the best way to utilize this in vb6? Is there a way I can expose this as an interface, or create a object in vb6 to match up?

I've searched MSDN but what's out there is pretty limited on the topic, rather not a common issue it seems.

Usually I expose everything via a interface, but something such as:

```
class myClass (string x, string y, string z);
```

won't work (interface cannot contain fields).

I've also tried

```
myClass(string x, string y, string z);
```

which I get an error method must have a return type.

Lastly I've tried

```
myClass iClass(string x, string y, string z);
```

which returns a does not implement interface member.

myClass

```
public string x {get;set;}
public string y {get;set;}
public string z {get;set;}
```

I can't find any accurately worded questions via search (perhaps my wording is off in the title, since again my vb6 knowledge is minimum).

All quoted code is from the c# dll.

Comment: One way is to create a COM callable wrapper in your C# code, then that can be accessed and used from the VB6 code simply as a regular COM object.  See the 
 COM callable wrapper sections in this tutorial, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/how-to-create-com-wrappers (it also explains runtime wrappers).  This references VS 2005, but should be similar for later VS releases.

Comment: You can have your class inherit a CCW-compatible interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can give your class a COM-callable wrapper, which VB6 can interoperate with.

This is your class, wrapped with a COM-callable wrapper callable from VB6:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CCW
{
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class myClass
    {
        public string x { get; set; }
        public string y { get; set; }
        public string z { get; set; }
    }
}
```